# proof: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \int_{0}^{a}f(nx)dx = aL$ when $\lim{x\to\infty }f(x)= L$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

we know that:

$\lim{x\to\infty }f(x)= L$

$\alpha > 0$

i need to prove that:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \int_{0}^{a}f(nx)dx = aL$

my idea was to get the limit inside the integral and then i will have this:

$\int_{0}^{a}L = L(a-0)$

but i am not sure that it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the limit inside the integral needs justification.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $T$ such that $|f(x)-L| <\epsilon$ for $x >T$, Note that $\int_0^{a}f(nx)dx=\frac  1n \int_0^{na} f(y)dy=\frac  1n \int_0^{T} f(y)dy+\frac  1n \int_T^{na} f(y)dy$. Show that the second term has values between $\frac {na-T} n (L-\epsilon)$ and $\frac {na-T} n (L+\epsilon)$. Also the  first term tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Can  you put these together to finish the proof?

Comment: I think you meant the second integral to be from $T$ to $na$.

Comment: @bjorn93 How careless can I get!

Comment: ok i understand and i can finish the proof, thank you very much!